# Find the adjoint operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> Consider the sequence space $\ell_p$ and S defined by
>   $(1\leq p<\infty)$$$ S:\ell_p\to\ell_p:(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)\mapsto(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)
>   $$
>   Find the  $S^*$ operator.

Comment: What are your thoughts, @ersanbatu?

Comment: if p=2 it's easy but other case?

Comment: The formula for the operator $S^*$ is the same (why?) if you correctly identify the dual space.

Comment: if p=2 than  Hilbert space and $$ S^* (x_0, x_1, x_2, \dotsc ),  = ( x_1, x_2, x_3, \dotsc )$$

Comment: So, what happens for other p?

Comment: Take $y^*\in \ell_p^*$ (note $y^*$ is a sequence). You can compute the $i$'th coordinate of $S^*y^*$ with the formula $(S^*y^*)e_i=y^*(Se_i)$, where $e_i$ is the $i$'th standard unit vector.

Comment: ok. Thanks so much..